# Best practices for getting layout weights to align imagebuttons perfectly during android activity?

Tags: android, xml, layout, imageview, scale

I'm having a hard time aligning up my image buttons properly during a android activity.  As you can see all the images are all shifted and not aligned properly.  And that was after a long time of adjustments.

My main XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"   
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:baselineAligned="true">
 <LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="158px" 
      android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:baselineAligned="true">  

    <ImageButton         
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"

        android:gravity="left" 
   android:adjustViewBounds="false"
  android:scaleType="fitStart"

        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="@drawable/topfula_r1_c1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:id="@+id/fluprepare"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       >

       </ImageButton>
    <ImageButton android:scaleType="fitCenter"        
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
   android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:gravity="left" 
        android:layout_gravity="left" android:background="@drawable/topfula_r1_c2" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/refreshflu" ></ImageButton>
    <ImageButton android:scaleType="fitEnd"        
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
         android:adjustViewBounds="false"
          android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:gravity="left" 
        android:layout_gravity="left" 
        android:background="@drawable/topfula_r1_c3" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/quitprogram" ></ImageButton>

</LinearLayout>   
 <LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="159px" 
      android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:baselineAligned="true">  

    <ImageButton         
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"

        android:gravity="left" 
   android:adjustViewBounds="false"
  android:scaleType="fitStart"

        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="@drawable/mid_r1_c1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:id="@+id/prepareflu"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       >

       </ImageButton>
    <ImageButton android:scaleType="fitCenter"        
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
   android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:gravity="left" 
        android:layout_gravity="left" android:background="@drawable/mid_r1_c2" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/maincdc" ></ImageButton>
    <ImageButton android:scaleType="fitEnd"        
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
         android:adjustViewBounds="false"
          android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:gravity="left" 
        android:layout_gravity="left" 
        android:background="@drawable/mid_r1_c3" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/configsettings" ></ImageButton>

</LinearLayout>   


<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_height="460px" 


   android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="horizontal" android:baselineAligned="true">

<ImageButton android:id="@+id/informationcards" 
android:background="@drawable/bottommain" 
android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"></ImageButton>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[Device Screen shot of layout not aligning](http://img830.imageshack.us/img830/7965/sneezeinyoursleevebysky.png)

As you can see there is a issue big time with the imagebuttons that I have initialy laid out as a test.  Using 1 large bottom image that pushes up 3 images in the top and middle rows that need to be aligned is difficult.

If any more detail is needed, please let me know.

[edit]

android:baselineAligned="true"
android:layout_weight="1"
     android:baselineAligned="true"

are just a nightmare to just have right.  it is like black magic to get it all perfect with multiple images and layouts that all have to be edge to edge...

I would love to instead of having the 3 layouts all in one larger Layout container seems awful..  a nice sweet grid with edge to edge?

[image: Original not Spliced up]

[image: Spliced and ImageButton'd up awww]

Whoo hoo!  I solved it with lots of trial and error! with 100x less code.  like wow.

Comment: It looks like it just doesn't all fit. Where do you want the extra space to come from?

Comment: it looks like the top layout height is little distored. and that throws it off.. and it also looks like the big bottom graphic is perhaps too large.. as the bottom image looks like it is almost wanting to tile...

Comment: You can see the video for the fixed layout at http://skyboardsoftware.com  :)

Comment: That's a nice word, "fixed"! :)

Comment: This came _very_ close to being removed as SPAM due to the voting encouragement in your question (and comments), please don't do that again. Additionally, it would be helpful if you provided the solution as an answer and accepted it, which takes this off of our list of unanswered questions.

Comment: Ohh yes yes indeed. Mr Post.  Adding aswer.  I just noticed that I could answer my own question. as I thought before it was not allowed.  sweet stuff. thanks.  yes the cdc voting was lots of pressure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a snippet from my main.xml file that I used in the above question...

you will see that it was not done with image buttons.  and the beauty of it all is that there is zero chance of image miss alignments. as you will notice the

```
   android:background="@drawable/mainlayoutbg2"
```

is one file.. not a whole bunch of pieced up images that you pray will all block together with all there weights and alignments...

```
<TableLayout
android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/mainlayoutbg2"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:clickable="true">
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:height="100px">
    <Button
        android:clickable="true"
        android:height="100px"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Button02"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="     "
        android:width="100px"></Button>

    <Button
        android:clickable="true"
        android:height="100px"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/refreshflud"
        android:onClick="refreshflu()"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="     "
        android:width="100px"></Button>

    <Button
        android:clickable="true"
        android:height="100px"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/refreshflub"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="     "
        android:width="100px"></Button>
    <Button
        android:clickable="true"
        android:height="100px"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/refreshfluc"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="     "
        android:width="100px"></Button>
    <Button
        android:height="100px"
        android:text="     "
        android:background="@null"
        android:width="100px"
        android:id="@+id/quitprogram"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>

</TableRow>
```

I hope this shaves off some hours from someone elses dev sessions.

Comment: Your setting all your button heights to 100 pixels, you no this will look different on each device? Try 100dip for better cross device compatability

Comment: ohh yes! nice one!    thx for formating the source. I was getting to that. :)  I thought I flipped the px to dip already.  nice catch.